# Mtree Add-On Installation

Tags: add-on

I would like to know what exactly I have to do to install this add-on, since what I tried didn´t work. I used already the zip-file, I used **init**.py both in the main folder and the python_classes folder. It´s for making trees. These are the relevant links:
https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree/releases
https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree

Comment: [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree#installation-blender-addon) are available on the web site.  Note that you do need to pick the version for your OS because it includes a compiled C++ binary.

Comment: Yes, i used the .dmg version for OS, but how do you know I have a Mac :/

Comment: @IrenäusBlaszkiewicz: I have a macbook - i could install it and see it in the list - but i couldn't click on the "enable" checkbox - i have no idea why. Maybe you should report an issue on the github page of the add-on. I made good experiences reporting issues - often they help you quick. my error was: cause: cannot import name 'm_tree' from partially initialized module 'modular_tree' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.2/scripts/addons/modular_tree/__init__.py)
addon not loaded: 'modular_tree'

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip file.

Then in Blender, go to the menu `Edit` > `Preferences`.
In the `Addons` category, click the `Install` button, select the zip file and validate.
After a few seconds it should display the addon alone in the addons list. You have successfully installed an addon.
Then all you have to do is to activate the addon by ticking its checkbox ON on the top left corner of the addon.

Most addons can be installed this way. When it's not the case, it is always in the addon's documentation.

Comment: The installation on itself seems to happen but it doesn´t display the add-on in the list when I search for it.